# Mix normal and Flow-'type' imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

So, in the docs of flow I usually see examples like these when it comes to importing types:

```
import type { someType } from './awesome'
import { somethingElse } from './awesome'
```

This is all fine and okay. However, I noticed that you can also do it like this:

```
import { somethingElse, type someType } from './awesome'
```

Is this considered to be a bad practice? If yes, why?
Thanks!
[example for doc](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/modules/#toc-importing-and-exporting-values)

Answer (score 1):

So, there's been an issue plaguing our codebase for *months* that just got resolved due to [this issue](https://github.com/speedskater/babel-plugin-rewire/issues/208), which came up from using `babel-plugin-rewire` with Flow and Babel. Essentially, doing the shorthand can trick Babel into thinking `someType` is a binding, when it's not, and support for handling this case is supposed removed in Babel 7. (I haven't tried Babel 7 yet, can't comment there.) For our own sanity and future safety, we've changed everything to have `import type` on a separate line.